# Difference between a 'runlevel' or a 'multiuser runlevel'?

Tags: 12.04, runlevel

Is there a difference when I say ***multiuser runlevel*** and when I say just ***runlevel*** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the only singleuser runlevel is 1, saying 'multiuser runlevel' implies a runlevel between 2 and 5. Just saying 'runlevel' would include 0 for shutdown, 6 for reboot., and of course 1 for single-user.